# mysql select in aescending or descending order

Tags: mysql

my id or primary key is and the data type of is VARCHAR(50)

```
            0.0.01
            0.0.100
            0.0.101
            0.0.1011
            0.0.201
            0.0.501
            0.0.99
            0.0.999
            0.01.0
            0.01.10
            0.02.10
            0.02.20
            0.02.99
            01.0.0
            01.0.99
            01.02.99
            01.03.444
            01.05.88
            10.02.99
            100.100.100
            25.45.1001
            99.99.99
```

I have to get it in sorted order
so i tried this

`select id from table order by cast(id as decimal) desc;`

but it does not work

the expected order is after running the query

```
            0.0.01
            0.0.99
            0.0.100
            0.0.101
            0.0.201
            0.0.501
            0.0.999
            0.0.1011
            0.01.0
            0.01.10
            0.02.10
            0.02.20
            0.02.99
            01.0.0
            01.0.99
            01.02.99
            01.03.444
            01.05.88
            10.02.99
            25.45.1001
            99.99.99
            100.100.100
```

i am using mysql for this

Comment: You don't have proper values in `id` `0.0.01` is invalid decimal value while `0.01` is valid that's why order by not working

Comment: yes right. but now is there a solution for this

Comment: @user310685 are these ip no.s ?

Comment: no they are version numbers

Comment: yes for 1 to 9 there are leading zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easier one but you can use `substring_index` for each decimal places

```
select *
from t
order by 
substring_index(id,'.',1) * 1,
substring_index(substring_index(id,'.',-2),'.',1) * 1,
substring_index(id,'.',-1) * 1
```

### Explanation

I have use `substring_index` what it does it will return the piece of string in provided column like in above case i have use `id` column by the occurrence of delimiter i.e(**.**) for example a string like **0.1.2** for above 3 sunstring_index usage will return as below

- `substring_index('0.1.2','.',1)` will give result as 0
- `substring_index(substring_index('0.1.2','.',-2),'.',1)`  will give result as 1
- `substring_index('0.1.2','.',-1)` will give result as 2

For type casting to number i have multiplied the result of `substring_index` to 1 so the order by expression will first order the results by the number before first dot then with number before second dot and last the number after second dot in ascending manner

[image]

[image]

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b80ee4/8)

Sources:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thank you for the answer . i am getting the right answer with this. but i did not get how is the logic working in this

Comment: @Moses See my updated answer hope you will get idea for the trick

Answer (score 0):

Your `ID` column has invalid decimal value so casting could not work here.

Try without casting this should work:

```
select id from table order by id desc;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c12753/1)

Comment: thanks for the comment . but i guess its not working. even in fiddle the output is not sorted i guess